# Posting contents of a file to slackbot

Tags: curl, slack

I have a bash script that checks some response codes from a few webservers, and saves it in a text file, example:

```
172.19.1.2 :: 200
172.19.2.3 :: 200
172.19.3.4 :: 200
172.19.4.5 :: 200
```

And I have a slackbot created and can get it to post simple text messages with this:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{"text":"Hello, World!"}' https://hooks.slack.com/services/sth/sth/sth
```

The question I have is, is there any way I can get the curl command to include the contents of the text file? I tried using @filename.txt, but all I get is invalid payload. Would appreciate any help! :)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm also getting invalid payload.